# Integration of Fourier Series for $f(x) = \frac{1-\frac{x}{\pi}}{2}$

Tags: fourier-series

I have to calculate the fourier series of
$$ f(x) = \frac{(1-x/\pi)}{2} $$
On the interval $ [0,\pi] $, I got:
$$ Sf(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n\pi} $$

Now, the problem begins: How to integrate (many times, maybe 3) using the Theorem for Integration of Fourier Series, and again the same calculation with the Parseval's Identity to get the known relation:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n⁴} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}. $$

I tried and not succeeded so far!
Calculations with the Parseval's Identity gave $\frac{(2\pi)^4}{90}$, 
I could not get rid of this 2-factor!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, please write what you have tried, and please use mathjax for math formatting.

Comment: On what interval are you taking the FS?  What was your result?  What issue is there in integrating term by term?

Comment: I wrote the interval and made the modifications with the mathjax! help!